# Why was my question on Male Genital Mutilation closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

I asked this question: [Why does the UK have Female Genital Mutilation Act 2003, but not Male Genital Mutilation Act?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/52488/27464) but despite explaining why it was not a duplicate, it still got closed without any reply to my explanations.

Answer (score 7):

There was a comment by the initial close-voter; I can't remember it exactly, but it was to the effect of:

> The UK and US are similar enough politically that the answer will be the same.

Unfortunately, they edited that comment into the auto-generated "Does this answer your question?" comment, which gets deleted once the question is closed, so you must not have been able to see it and reply to it before that happened.

I'm not familiar enough with the questions to be able to judge whether this explanation is valid, but that's the explanation that was given by the close-voters.

(The question has since been deleted, and in all honesty, I think it should stay that way. Regardless of whether it was a duplicate or not, it strongly came across as a push question/attempt to discredit, whereas the earlier question was a genuine, neutrally-worded inquiry. I too am not fond of infant circumcision, but Politics.SE is not the place to rally about it.)

Comment: Agreed, I would have VTC this one as a "push" question given the material in it. The OP might have a semi-valid question whether there are any differences in how the matter is debated in the UK vs the US, but they way they asked about it seemed quite ranty.

Comment: Closing as duplicate a bad-faith question is like getting Al Capone for tax evasion.

Comment: First, I never meant my question "came across as a push question/attempt to discredit". I don't get it how it can strongly come across as one? I just cited facts.

Comment: Second, how to make it more "genuine, neutrally-worded inquiry"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Isn't it "bad-faith" to write that I wrote "a bad-faith question"? i've tried to explain that i asked in GOOD faith with facts.

Comment: If the 'initial comment' was what prompted the dupe, then [it's historically wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcision#Modern_times). Rates and rationales given for non-religious procedures are vastly different as well as attitudes towards how to 'judge' religious ones. Who on the l/r-spectrum positions (usually) on this as well. (The Q itself may have been substandard, but the reason given imo much more so. The dupe target far from giving any suitable As. Problem for both: less political but philosophical/ethical/moral value judgements & considerations are the key, yet As try 'facts')

Answer (score 2):

Regarding my VTD: your question consisted of two large quotes one from

> 'My son killed himself after circumcision' - BBC News (2019)

and

> David Reimer - Wikipedia

And based on that you ask "Why hasn't the UK enacted a male version of Female Genital Mutilation Act 2003"?

Why would they enact an Act based on two cases, even if they are what you say they are, which also seems to be a confusion as the two cases seem hardly comparable in terms of the medical act?

You assert in your "question" that the US one

> doesn't discuss suicides and mental illnesses from non-consensual circumcision.

As if those effects (suicide & mental illness) are *common* consequences of circumcision, based on the two cases you've discovered and so [*should*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question) be discussed?